# How to convert numeric time into date, time format in R

Tags: r, datetime, xts

Trying to build an xts for my data. The date fromat it okay but I dont know how to convert "time" column into a time format. Time is stored as numeric, the data looks like:

```
      date time  price
1 19900102  930 353.40
2 19900102  931 353.25
3 19900102  932 353.02
4 19900102  933 352.97
5 19900102  934 352.81
6 19900102  935 352.74
```

I tried the following code but it doesnt work.

```
sp500.xts <-  as.xts(sp500[,3],order.by=as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(as.character(sp500[,1]),as.character(sp500[,2])),"%Y%m%d %H:%M")))
```

Thanks for anyone who helps.

Comment: Is date `YYYYMMDD` and time `09:30`am, `09:31`am, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big fan of `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` and the `timetk` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(timetk)

test %>%
  mutate(date = parse_date_time(paste(date, str_pad(time, 4, side = "left", pad = "0")), "YmdHM")) %>%
  select(-time) %>%
  tk_xts(silent = T)

                     price
1990-01-02 09:30:00 353.40
1990-01-02 09:31:00 353.25
1990-01-02 09:32:00 353.02
1990-01-02 09:33:00 352.97
1990-01-02 09:34:00 352.81
1990-01-02 09:35:00 352.74
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `930 = 09:30`, may try this:

`timec` is to pad to get the full hm; `dtc` is to get the full date time, then use `ymd_hm` to read into datetime format.

```
library(tidyverse)

library(lubridate)


test %>% 
  mutate(timec = str_pad(time, 4, side = 'left', pad = '0'),
         dtc = str_c(date, timec),
         dt = ymd_hm(dtc))

> test %>% 
+   mutate(timec = str_pad(time, 4, side = 'left', pad = '0'),
+          dtc = str_c(date, timec),
+          dt = ymd_hm(dtc))
      date time  price timec          dtc                  dt
1 19900102  930 353.40  0930 199001020930 1990-01-02 09:30:00
2 19900102  931 353.25  0931 199001020931 1990-01-02 09:31:00
3 19900102  932 353.02  0932 199001020932 1990-01-02 09:32:00
4 19900102  933 352.97  0933 199001020933 1990-01-02 09:33:00
5 19900102  934 352.81  0934 199001020934 1990-01-02 09:34:00
6 19900102  935 352.74  0935 199001020935 1990-01-02 09:35:00
```